# Ruby - Open3 popen3 function sanitized

Tags: ruby, popen3

would like to run a system command on ruby using popen3 function from Open3. It would be something like:

```
pdf2htmlEX --zoom 1.3 ~/test.pdf
```

As the filename will be passed by params, I would like to sanitize it. if run, for example:

```
Open3.popen3("pdf2htmlEX --zoom 1.3 ~/test.pdf") do |stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr|

end
```

The code works fine, but when I try to separate the argument (as the functions suggests that way it would be escaped), something like:

```
Open3.popen3("pdf2htmlEX --zoom 1.3", "~/test.pdf") do |stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr|

end
```

it gives me the error: No such file or directory - pdf2htmlEX --zoom 1.3

does anyone knows how I fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The arguments need to be separate from the command. Try

`Open3.popen3("pdf2htmlEX", "--zoom", "1.3", "~/test.pdf")...`

Comment: But now I got the error of unrecognized option "--zoom 1.3". Removed it, and then, "I/O Error: Couldn't open file '~/test.pdf': No such file or directory.", even the file existing (and it worked if I passed the entire command as a unique string). Any ideas?

Comment: with the absolute path, worked... but still getting error om zoom param

Comment: all the arguments need to be specified separately in the array - I corrected the command syntax

Comment: The shell replaces '~' with your home directory. That doesn't work in a script/program.